# Animate Property of Custom Class

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, win-universal-app, dependency-properties

In my UWP project, I bind several elements on the page to various objects which are then updated. One of these objects is a custom class with an attached DependencyProperty called Background. Background, in my class, is defined as a SolidColorBrush.

When animating the background of an element directly, say, a Button, I would use:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)");
```

So, when trying to animate the Background property of my custom class, I write:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "(MyClass.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)");
```

This gives me the error:

```
Cannot resolve TargetProperty (MyClass.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)
```

How can I correctly animate the dependencyproperty of my custom class?

Comment: Please  show your custom class.

Comment: `Storyboard` targets on controls,whether you use a `UserControl` or a `Templated Control`, there is no way to attach DependencyProperty called Background, because this property hides inherited member `Control.Background`, you will need to provide more information for this problem.

Comment: Thanks, Grace Feng... I changed my class to inherit from UserControl, removed my custom property Background, and animated the inherited property instead. Now objects bound to it animate correctly.

However, it was my understanding that UserControls aren't meant to be binding sources, but rather targets. Should I worry about that or, since it works, just let it be?

Comment: @BenjaminChambers, sorry, didn't see your comment until today I review my case. Yes, dependency property of the controls are normally binding targets, but sometimes they can be binding sources too, for example, binding the text of `TextBlock` to the text of a `TextBox`. In this case, usercontrol is binding target.